# Agregar Queries desde archivo de configuracion spring data JPA para hacer @query(nativeQuery)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, archivo-de-propiedades, spring-data

estoy practicando Spring Data JPA usando queries nativas, pero al querer separar las queries de mi código fuente, me da error, ya que no la referencio bien.

¿Cómo debo referenciar queries del archivo application.properties?

Este es mi código

```
@Repository
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public interface BicycleRepository extends CrudRepository<Bicycle, Long>
{
    @Query(value = "${Bycicle.findAll}", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Bicycle> obtenerTodos();
}
```

Y en archivo de propiedades está la consulta

```
Bycicle.findAll=SELECT * from bicycle
```

No se sustituye el ${Bycicle.findAll} por la consulta del archivo de configuración